# How to solve this unknown error PHPMyAdmin?

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin, xampp, laragon

So I want to upgrade my PHP version on XAMPP, then I found some errors when I want to access PHPMyAdmin. After I consulted my senior, my senior said to reinstall XAMPP or just change to Laragon. After I followed all the suggestions, I still found the error, it's just that the error was different and difficult to solve. [Here screenshot of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuGet.jpg)

Please Help Me Without Ask Me To Reinstall My Windows.

Thanks

Comment: php isn't installed or isnt installed correctly.

Comment: I think the php is installed correctly, I've checked via CMD

Comment: You mean the cli? PHP-CLI can be installed / set up properly while also being installed incorrectly for your middleware.

Comment: I don't think it's cli. I can run my php project, i also run my mysql. But when i want to access phpmyadmin to help me doing my job, that's error happend